Flutter Hive, data not write to local
I created an app that fetches data from local storage using hive, when I tried to call the updateData, the data list is a empty list, here's my code
home_page.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hive_ex_14aug/data/database_user_list.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //reference hive box
  var mybox = Hive.box("mybox");

  //refence database
  DatabaseUserList db = DatabaseUserList();

  //init state
  @override
  void initState() {
    //check
    if (mybox.get("userList") == null) {
      db.createSampleData();
      print("userList database is null");
    } else {
      print("userList database found");
      db.loadData();
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: db.userList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(db.userList[index][0]),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
            )),
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    db.userList.add([_controller.text]);
                    print(db.userList);
                    db.updateData();
                    // mybox.put("userList", [_controller.text]);
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Add"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


database_user_list.dart:
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class DatabaseUserList {
  //reference hive box
  var mybox = Hive.box("mybox");

  List userList = [];

  void createSampleData() {
    userList = [
      ["Chris"],
      ["Steve"],
    ];
  }

  void loadData() {
    mybox.get("userList");
  }

  //update data
  void updateData() {
    mybox.put("userList", userList);
  }
}


When the add button is clicked, new name is displayed in listview, however, it has not been written to the local database.
